# If else/ for loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Is there any way to make this if-else statement generalized. Right now the truthArray consists of values from t1 to t4. I am looking for a way to create a generalized solution for any number of values t5, t6 and so on. I am not getting how to tell the for loop to create more and more nested if statements depending on the lenght of the truth array. Thanks. 
Explanation of code:
First of all I want to check if t1 is true. If it is so then the first element in the positionArray will be 'left'. Now I want to check the value of t2 when t1 is already established as true. If t2 is true then I set the second element in positionArray as 'right'. After that I want to check if t3 is true when t1 and t2 are already true and set the third element of positionArray as left. Then I am checking if t4 is true when t1, t2, t3 all are true and so on. The consecutive elements of positionArray thus will be right, then left, then right then left and so on.
Now if t1 is not true then I want to start the same process from t2. If t1 is not true the first element of position array will be undefined. If t1 is not true and t2 is true, then the second element of positionArray is set as 'left' and the consecutive elemenets will be right, left, right and so on..
If t1 and t2 both are not true then the process will start from t3 and so on..

```js
            var truthArray = [t1, t2, t3, t4]; 
            var positionArray = [];
            var i;        
  
           
            if (truthArray[0] === true) {
                positionArray[0] = 'left';
                if (truthArray[1] === true) {
                    positionArray[1] = 'right';
                    if (truthArray[2] === true) {
                        positionArray[2] = 'left';
                        if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                            positionArray[3] = 'right';
                        }
                    }
                    else if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                        positionArray[3] = 'left';
                    }
                }
                else if (truthArray[2] === true) {
                    positionArray[2] = 'right';
                    if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                        positionArray[3] = 'left';
                    }
                }
                else if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                    positionArray[3] = 'right';
                }
            }
            else if (truthArray[1] === true) {
                positionArray[1] = 'left';
                if (truthArray[2] === true) {
                    positionArray[2] = 'right';
                    if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                        positionArray[3] = 'left';
                    }
                }
                else if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                    positionArray[3] = 'right';
                }
            }
            else if (truthArray[2] === true) {
                positionArray[2] = 'left';
                if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                    positionArray[3] = 'right';
                }
            }
            else if (truthArray[3] === true) {
                positionArray[3] = 'left';
            }
```

Comment: `if`/`else` != loop

Comment: corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I can't figure what the underlying logic is so I can't tell what a generalized solution would be. Can you provide an overview of the general logic you're trying to implement?

Comment: Why are all these IFs nested? Please edit your question with an explanation of what you’re trying to do .

Comment: Added the explanation now. Hope it clarifies what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this might help you, let me know if you face any issue

```
var truthArray = [false, false, true]; 
var positionArray = [];
var positionArrayValues = ['left','right'];
var offsetArray = [];
var start = 0, end = truthArray.length;      
function traverseFurther(index,positionArrayIndex) {
    if(index === end)
        return;
    if(truthArray[index] === true) {
        positionArray[index] = positionArrayValues[positionArrayIndex];
        traverseFurther(index + 1, positionArrayIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0);
    } else {
        traverseFurther(index + 1,positionArrayIndex);
    }
}
traverseFurther(start, 0);
```

Comment: Works with slight modification. Just needed to do this :positionArrayIndex  %2 == 0 ? 1 : 0.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to loop through `truthValues` and build a `positionArray` where **if** (truthValue == false) add `undefined` to `positionArray` **else** add either `'left'` or `'right'` to the `positionArray` such that `'left'` and `'right'` always alternate?

Here is how you could do that.

```js
    //fill truthArray with 10 random boolean values
    const truthArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      truthArray.push(Math.random() > 0.5);
    }
    
    //calc(truthArray) and map the result (and truthInput) to make it easier to read
    const input = truthArray.map(t => t?'T':'F');
    const output = calc(truthArray).map(v => {
      if (v === 'left') return 'L';
      if (v === 'right') return 'R';
      if (v === undefined) return '-';
    });
    
    //display truthInput and result
    console.log('T is true, F is false');
    console.log('L is left, R is right, - is undefined');
    console.log(input.join());
    console.log(output.join());
    
    function calc(truthArray) {
      var trueCount = 0;
      const result = [];
      for (var truthVal of truthArray) {
        if (truthVal) {
          const position = (trueCount % 2 == 0)
            ? 'left'
            : 'right';
          result.push(position);
          trueCount++;
        } else {
          result.push(undefined);
        }
      }
      
      return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just map the check and return either a toggled value or `undefined`.

It works by checking the value of the element and takes a [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) with an object and a value `pos`. This value changes by assigning a new value to `pos` by taking `pos` as [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for the object.

> ```
> rl = { right: 'left', left: 'right' }
> pos = 'right';
> pos = rl[pos]; // left
> pos = rl[pos]; // right
> pos = rl[pos]; // left
> pos = rl[pos]; // right
> // and so on ...
> ```

If the element is not [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), then `undefined` is mapped to the result set.

```js
var truthArray = [false, true, false, true],
    lr = { right: 'left', left: 'right' },
    pos = 'right',
    positionArray = truthArray.map(b => b ? pos = lr[pos] : undefined);

console.log(positionArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For getting a different pattern, like

```
['left', 'left', 'right', 'right']
```

you could increment the index and adjust it with the remainder operator and take a bithifted value to right, which divides the value by `2` and returns an integer value.

```js
var truthArray = [true, false, true, false, true, false, true, false, true],
    lr = ['left', 'right'],
    pos = 3,
    positionArray = truthArray.map(b => b ? lr[++pos, (pos %= 4) >> 1] : undefined);

console.log(positionArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is happening in this code. It works but I did not understand the logic.

Comment: @ Nina, got it. Thanks. And how can we make it alternate as left,left,right,right instead of left,right,left,right?

Comment: then take an index variable and increment by one and get the value of the array by  a bitshifted value (right by one, which takes an integer) and adjust with a remainder operator.